# Passing an list to Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
public List<double> GoogleGeoCode(string address)
        {
            address = "Stockholm";
            string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=";

            dynamic googleResults = new Uri(url + address).GetDynamicJsonObject();

            var cordinates = new List<double>();

            foreach (var result in googleResults.results)
            {

                cordinates.Add(result.geometry.location.lng);

                cordinates.Add(result.geometry.location.lat);

            }

            return cordinates;

        }
```

Now, I want two use the values in the list in my Ajax:

```
 $(function() {
                    $('#ajax').click(function() {
                        $.ajax({

                                url: '@Url.Action("GoogleGeoCode", "Home")',
                                context: document.body
                            })
                            .done(function(serverdata) {
                                data = serverdata;
                                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        'position': new google.maps.LatLng(item[0], item.GeoLat[1]), <-- I thought Item would contain my list and I could use its index
                                        'map': map,
                                        'title': item.PlaceName,
                                        'Catch': item.Catch

                                    });
                                });
                            });
                    });
```

Im a beginner with Ajax i would really appreciate a step by step explanation on how it works if someone got the time. Thanks!

Updat:
New class:

```
public class LongLatModel
    {
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public LongLatModel GoogleGeoCode(string address)
        {
            address = "Stockholm";
            string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=";

            dynamic googleResults = new Uri(url + address).GetDynamicJsonObject();

            var cordinates = new List<double>();

            var longlat = new LongLatModel();


            foreach (var result in googleResults.results)
            {

                longlat.Latitude = result.geometry.location.lng;

                longlat.Longitude = result.geometry.location.lat;

            }

            return longlat;

        }
```

Ajax:

```
$(function() {
                    $('#ajax').click(function() {
                        $.ajax({
                                // in a real scenario, use data-attrs on the html
                                // rather than linking directly to the url
                                url: '@Url.Action("GoogleGeoCode", "Home")',
                                context: document.body
                            })
                            .done(function(serverdata) {
                                data = serverdata;
                                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        'position': new google.maps.LatLng(data.longitude, data.latitude),
                                        'map': map,
                                        'title': item.PlaceName,
                                        'Catch': item.Catch

                                    });
                                });
                            });
                    });
```

EDIT:

Ok, so I managed to get the right info into the AJAX (i think..)
However, I have trouble relising how to place these two values where they are supposed to be.

[image]

How can i loop throgh and place them in the right place?

$.each(data, function (i, item) {

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(LONG, LAT),

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the C# method, you should create a data strucutre for LatLog, instead of returning a List<double> in the method.

   ```
   class LatLongModel
   {
       public double Latitude {get;set;}
       public double Longitude{get;set;}
   }
   ```
2. In JavaScript, in the done method, you can then check:

   ```
   data.Longitude; data.Latitude;
   ```
3. You also should add fail in the Ajax request in case the request fails.  Check out this snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/JhWt4/

**Update**

In the C# code you want to create and return a List

```
    public class GeoCodeResultModel
    {
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public string PlaceName { get; set; }
        public string Catch { get; set; }
    }

    public List<GeoCodeResultModel> GoogleGeoCode(string address)
    {
        address = "Stockholm";
        string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=";

        dynamic googleResults = new Uri(url + address).GetDynamicJsonObject();

        var locations = new List<GeoCodeResultModel>();

        foreach (var result in googleResults.results)
        {
            locations.Add(new GeoCodeResultModel
            {
                 Longitude = result.geometry.location.lng,
                 Latitude = result.geometry.location.lat,
                 PlaceName = 'TODO',
                 Catch = 'TODO'
            }
        }

        return locations;

    }
```

For the JavaScript Code:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude), 
                 'map': map,
                 'title': item.PlaceName,
                 'Catch': item.Catch
    });
});
```

**Disclaimer:** This isn't tested code, it's to point you in the right direction.

Comment: So I should Creat the class LatLongModel and then create an instance of it in the method and pass the model to the Js?
Thanks for your time btw!

Comment: Yes.  Create that class, instantiate it with the correct values, and return the instance in the method.

Comment: @user2915962 Do you expect multiple results from googleResults.results?

Comment: at this point no, I have now created the model that passes the two vaules (long/lat) to the Ajax. Pls see my update. Dunno if the ajax is right.

Comment: @user2915962 If you expect multiple lat and long, then you want to return List<LatLongModel> in C#.  In the JS done method, you can then loop through the data and access the lat long, like data[0].Latitude, etc.

Comment: @user2915962 You should return List<LatLongModel>.  And add items to that list in the loop.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: You also need to add Placename and Catch to the LatLongModel, so you might be better off renaming that to GeoCodeResultModel.

Comment: Thanks you vermuch for your time, I´ll try aound with this and get back to acept answer if I get it right! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it possible maybe to add an alert(item.Lobgitude) in the code to see if I have it with me?

Comment: @user2915962 You can do better, check out JavaScript debugging in Google Chrome. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging. Press F12 to open the dev tools.  In the sources tab, you can set breakpoints on the code. Once break point hits, you can observe the values in the right panel, or in the console.

Comment: Please have a look at my update if you have the time. Thank you!

Comment: I got it to work this morning with you help! Thank you!